# Trying to scrape multiple pages sequentially using loop to change url

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, web-scraping

First off, sorry... I am sure that this is a common problem but i did not find the solution anywhere eventhough i searched for a while.

I am trying to create list by scraping data from classicdb. The two problems i have is.

1. The scraping as written in the try loop does not work in inside the for loop but on its own it works. Currently it just returns the 0 even though there should be values to return.
2. The output that i get from the try loop gernerates new lists but i want to just get the value and append it later.

I have tried the try function outside the for loop and there it worked.
I also saw some solutions where a while true was used but that did not work for me.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests

import traceback
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

Item_name=[]
Sell_Copper=[]


items= [47, 48]
url = 'https://classic.wowhead.com/item='
fails=[]


for i in items:

        time.sleep(5)
        url1=(url+str(i))
        session = requests.session()
        response = session.get(url1)
        soup = bs(response.content, 'lxml')
        name=soup.select_one('h1').text
        print(name)

        #get the buy prices
        try:
            copper = soup.select_one('li:contains("Sells for") .moneycopper').text
        except Exception as e:
            copper=str(0)
```

The expected result would be that i get one value in gold and a list in P_Gold. In this case:
copper='1'
Sell_copper=['1','1']

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a sleep. It needs to be div:contains and the search text needs changing

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

Item_name=[]
Sell_Copper=[]
items= [47, 48]
url = 'https://classic.wowhead.com/item='
fails=[]

with requests.Session() as s:
    for i in items:
        response = s.get(url + str(i))
        soup = bs(response.content, 'lxml')
        name = soup.select_one('h1').text
        print(name)

        try:
            copper = soup.select_one('div:contains("Sell Price") .moneycopper').text
        except Exception as e:
            copper=str(0)
        print(copper)
```

Comment: Did you try this?